# Mass assignment on self relationship in Laravel (do I need to create model?)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am designing shop solution in Laravel 5.2.

Now, I am stuck with a problem. I am creating self relation (one product can have many related products), like this

```
public function related()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(self::class, 'related', 'product_id', 'related_id');
}
```

Now, let's presume I got array of related products ids from form. How can I mass assign them? Seems I cannot do this without creating model for Related. Or can I?

Comment: Do you have models for `product` and `related` ?

Comment: I have model for product, of course, point of question is - do I need to create one for related too?

Comment: Yes, There should be model for every tables in your database. Also you need to set the $fillable property to mass assign

Comment: No, really I just read documentation more carefully and understood I do not need model, cause I can manage self relations with $product->related()->sync(/* array of product ids */); Should I now close the question or provide answer?

Comment: No need to answer now, I corrected Khaled's answer instead)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pivot table for many to many relation doesn't need model.

So you have to create pivot table "related" and make on it "product" function to set the relation.

and this link discuss that point: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many.

You can use sync function like $product->related()->sync(/* product ids array */); to manage the relation.

Comment: Seems you have right idea, I din't check the documentation good enough. I slightly corrected your answer and added some points. Thanks.